# delay between Camera.takephoto and callback

Tags: java, android, camera

guys. I am trying to use custom camera and found one problem: i have delay for 1 second between camera.takephoto and callback (onTakePicture). But why, because i havent any delay in default camera, when i take some photos, it works very faster, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(Error e){

}
```